# Is the color of a lightsaber significant? What causes it?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

This question always prevailed at the back of my mind. Does the lightsaber color hold any significance? Is the red beam more effective than the blue/green/purple beam or the other way round? Or is it just the normal wavelength physics of the plasma used in constructing?

Comment: Are you asking about in-movies ('canon'), or including EU/novels/games?

Comment: Movies specifically.

Comment: I think this might help..

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/what-is-the-reason-that-lightsabers-have-different-colors

Comment: Overall.  But if, as indicated, it's about the movies- there are production reasons that the answer to your linked question doesn't cover and actually 'short' the EU/x-canon reasons.

Comment: Well, the effectiveness or the 'power' of the saber varies with the color is what I wanted to know.