# Use of a yellow crystal in Canon Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-clone-wars, lightsaber

In the 2008 Clone Wars TV Series, we encounter the Jedi Temple Guards who protect the Temple, wielding shortened double-bladed yellow lightsabers.

Can only these Temple Guards use a yellow crystal, as a way to identify and make them more significant (both in and out of Universe), or has no Jedi been chosen by a yellow crystal?

[image]

Comment: related, not duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1779/20774

Comment: Which canon are we talking about here? The pre-mid-2014 canon included all the books, comics, games, etc - ranking some things as more canon than others. The new canon includes only the movies, novelizations/scripts and the tv shows.

Comment: Wasn't Plo Koon a yellow blade?

Comment: @RobertWertz I was thinking of Plo Koon as well, but I cannot remember where I saw him with a yellow lightsabre ... This gallery on the [official site](http://www.starwars.com/plo-koon-biography-gallery), showing images from the movies and the CG Clone Wars cartoon, always shows him with a blue one. Maybe in the Tartakovsky's Clone Wars cartoon, or some Battlefront videogame?

Comment: @Ifurini I know the very old (PS1 era) Jedi Power Battles had him as yellow, I thought there were other instances as well but I'm not 100% on anything else. I know there are color options for KotOR and Force Unleashed, but those are more customization than canon. Honestly can't think of anything else right now, but will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force), Jedi '[Sentinels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Sentinel)' were amongst those that use a yellow-bladed Lightsabers.

These "sentinels" were responsible for outreach programs such as intelligence-gathering, investigation, spying, technical specialism and sabotage:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In the clone wars, ahsoka's second lightsaber is actually a smaller yellow

Comment: Do you have an image you can add to your answer?

Comment: The Wikia identifies is as a "Yellow-Green" bladed weapon; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jar%27Kai/Canon. http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/a/af/AhsokaLightsabers-Overlords.png

Comment: The official [image gallery](http://www.starwars.com/databank/ahsoka-tano-biography-gallery) for Ahsoka has a couple images where she wields a yellow lightsaber.