# How does kyber crystal purification work?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, ahsoka-tano

Wookieepedia suggests that Ahsoka's lightsabers are white because she took red crystals and purified them:

> "Ahsoka obtained the kyber crystals used in these lightsabers one year after the end of the Clone Wars, retrieving them from the lightsaber of Sixth Brother, an Inquisitor she had killed. Though the crystals originally emitted a red blade, she had purified them from the darkness tainting them, by her description."
>    <sub>[*Wookieepedia - Ahsoka Tano's White Lightsabers*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano's_white_lightsabers)</sub>

**If so, what is the process of this purification? Does purification always lead to a white lightsaber?**

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1779/51379

Comment: @Adamant is it rude if I now edit my question to make it about the process of purification, or should I close and ask a new question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason that lightsabers have different colors?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/what-is-the-reason-that-lightsabers-have-different-colors)

Comment: Hmmmm currently it is 2 questions that should be put into one "what is a purification of a kyber crystal" (how does it work and what are the effects). As in all honesty I think the reason for teh white........nobody could answer there at all....if its the natural color of those kyber crystals or a result of the purificatoin,...

Comment: @Adamant That's... not the same at all. This is about asking how "purifying" a crystal would change its color.

Comment: @Terriblefan - That’s why it’s only a “possible” duplicate, and I didn’t hammer it closed. I wasn’t sure, but some might think that a question that explained the reasons behind the colors of *all*  lightsabers, including the white ones, might be a dupe.

Comment: @Thomas - Lightsaber crystals are naturally colorless. The Jedi can attune and change their color, and the Sith can impose their will and do the same. Ahsoka restored the crystals to their original colorless state, and so they didn’t change the color of the plasma blade.

Comment: @Adamant but colourless isn't white? Can a crystal just be changed at will?

Comment: @Edlothiad - The *crystal* is colorless. If you pass white light through a colorless crystal, its color doesn’t change (not counting prismatic effects etc.) So the *lightsaber* is white. As for a crystal being changed “at will,” probably not (only with difficulty), and there wouldn’t really be a point.

Comment: @Adamant, it seems my misunderstanding came from the fact I thought it was the crystal that changed colour, and not the lightsaber.

Comment: @Edlothiad - It’s both. It’s just that “colorless crystal” = “white lightsaber.”

Comment: How does kyber crystal purification work? Anyone? Alright then... *very well, thank you.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### How does "purification" happen?

Based on what happens in the canon novel *Ahsoka*, crystals are purified by meditating with them; this is essentially the only thing Ahsoka does between the Inquisitor's (red) lightsaber exploding and her (white) lightsabers igniting:

> Before she could even consider shouting a warning, the red lightsaber burst into a mess of noise and light. Bright spots pricked at her eyes, and then all was quiet. The creature wasn't going to bother her anymore.
>
> *[...]*
>
> She pushed aside her sense of urgency, even though she was in a hurry. Meditation came easily, as if she were sitting in safety in the Jedi Temple itself, instead of a dusty street with her enemies closing in. Her mind's eye sorted the preassembled components and those she had just retrieved into order, locking each into place with the others. When Ahsoka opened her hands, she was
>   not surprised to find that two lightsabers, rough and unfinished, were waiting.
>
> They would need more work, but they were *hers*.
>
> When she turned them on, they shone the brightest white.
>
> <sup>*Ahsoka* Chapter 28</sup>

Presumably, within the Force this is Ahsoka creating a bond with her crystal; Pablo Hidalgo has said [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/796226960133193728) that this is how crystals change colour for Jedi, which is one of the few things we know about the process:

[image: screencap of Twitter conversation]

> **@primagrine** what determines a light sider's lightsaber colour? do the crystals [have] anythin[g] to do w[ith] it [?]
>
> **@pablohidalgo** The crystal takes on a color when a Jedi achieves a bond with "his/her" kyber. No one knows what the colors signify.

On an internal level, "purification" would seem to be resolving the Dark Side/Light Side conflict within the crystal; *Ahsoka* suggests that crystals are turned red by tipping the scales in favour of the Dark (emphasis mine):

> *Dark crystals were made, too, but not in that holy place. They were plundered from their rightful bearers and corrupted by the hands that stole them. Even rock could be changed by the power of the Force, bleeding alterations until their color was the deepest red. **The balance was finely staged between the two, light and dark, and it took very little to upset it**.*
>
> <sup>*Ahsoka*</sup>

Whether or not a crystal can be "purified" by anyone, or just by the person that crystal chooses as its proper bearer, is unknown.

### Does "purification" always result in a white (or colourless) crystal?

We don't know; *Ahsoka* is the only example we have of this process in action, and her lightsaber colour explicitly [symbolizes](https://www.starwars.com/video/rebels-recon-inside-fire-across-the-galaxy) her detachment from both the Jedi and the Sith. Even Pablo Hidalgo doesn't know, having been asked this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/796945654543052800):

[image: screencap of Twitter conversation]

> **@ReyaShankar** Do red crystals turn only white when restored or can they change to other colors as well?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Unknown. In fact, Ahsoka was very surprised when it happened.

If forced to guess, I would assume that a "purified" crystal would turn to whatever colour was appropriate for the person who bonded with it; so, for example, Luke could have purified the crystal in Vader's lightsaber and turned it green. But this is, of course, only a guess.

Comment: I *suspect* (I’m not entirely sure), that Ahsoka returned the crystal to its previous colorless state. It’s not just a special color that’s appropriate to her Force powers/personality. But I can’t be sure.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to how Lucas intended original lighsabers to work; e.g. Darth Vader would pick Luke's lightsabers and it would turn red. I don't remember where I read this though.

Comment: ...We got rid of the EU version, wherein lightsaber colors were due to a colored crystal, for *this*?

Comment: @Terriblefan Yup. *And this is better.*

Comment: How silly of me. I don't know why I bothered taking things like inorganic chemistry and materials science in grad school. All I needed to do was meditate.